Is it possible to do uncertainty propagation with TF2? If not what can I use?
I'm interested in applying a sequence of linear transformations to a gaussian probability vector in TF2. As far as I understand this is a pretty operation due to the gaussian nature and I see TF2 has a pose_with_covariance object but I don't see a way to transform the covariance with a linear operation.
